React native can't access ngrok URL serving laravel
I put my ngrok URL the listen to port 800 for laravel but when I put it inside APP_URL in react native it can't reach the url ngrok. but when I access ngrok URL via web i can access it.
I run laravel using php artisan serve --host={my IP address} --port={8000}
ngrok http http://{my IP address}:{8000}
// for react native const 
const API_URL = "https://example.ngrok-free.app";

I tried testing ngrok forwarding URL on web and it works but not on react native.
I want to test the front-end to connect to the backend services via ngrok. I tried testing ngrok forwarding URL on web and it works but not on react native.
